# Different reports with similar SQL

Tags: reporting-services

I am writing departmental reports for my company in SSRS.  Each department will have access only to the report for their department.  The thing is that the SQL will be pretty much the same for each report, with department being the only variable.  I'm thinking that maybe each report would link to a sub-report that would be common to them all.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is it going to be the same report, simply filtering on the dept. or are the reports going to have different layouts just using the same SQL?

Comment: Same report.  The problem is that each report will be secured so that only the folks in department A can see the department A report and so on.  That's why I'm thinking sub-reports, but wanted to see if there was a more elegant solution out there.

Comment: You can retrieve the userID of the person accessing the report, so if you can translate this to retrieve their department you can get away with 1 report filtering based on userID.

Comment: They can only see the data for their department, as other departments data is being filtered out behind the scenes.

Comment: In general, you probably want to use a stored procedure whenever multiple reports are using same or similar queries, with parameters for UserID or DeptNo or whatever. This improves maintainability. When you update the stored procedures, then all reports get the updated version. Otherwise, some reports typically get forgotten, and they are then left in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I wound up doing:
I set up a shared dataset that did the heavy lifting with a parameter that specified the department.  Each report then used that dataset, passing it the department ID as the parameter to said dataset.  Works like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are planning to display or send out this report.  But you can use the department as a parameter in the SQL query.  That way you only need to use one report.  This can be passed in various different ways depending on how you are making this report available.  Example, the user's profile would have an associated department.

Using one report will help tremendously down the line when you are maintaining it or troubleshooting issues.

Comment: We're displaying the report over a web portal.  I had thought of your solution, but the problem is that the folks in department A don't want the folks in department B to see department A's report.  If someone from department B gets the link, then there's nothing stopping them from seeing what they shouldn't.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson that's your problem right there - You need to lock it down so that only people in group A can see certain reports. SSRS is good with Windows permissions. Can your domain admins create groups, or do they exist, that you could then assign view rights on reports to? Then you give each group a report that calls a base report, where each group's report provides a different parameter to the base report.

Comment: Does your web portal use any sort of login or windows authentication? If not, I would suggest you grab the user's loginname using Environment.UserName. You can then use this value to cross-reference from the database on what department they should be retrieving for. Without knowing your web portal's setup, it would be hard to suggest the most secure and appropriate method.

Comment: Meff: Is the notion of a base report calling another report the same thing as using a sub-report?

Comment: Michael, if one report is nested within another report, then that is technically a sub-report.

Comment: Yep, but Meff made it sound like one report called another.

Comment: I don't think Meff was implying that.  I am assuming he was suggesting the same thing as supplying a parameter to the SQL query for the one report.  Your best bet is to have just one report and have specific business/security logic assuring the person who is retrieving the report is allowed to see the result-set for that department.